# How to remove superglue/instant glue from clothing

Tags: cleaning, clothing

My favourite pair of jeans has fallen victim to a stray drip of superglue/instant glue. Now there is a small solid stain, with the glue partly embedded into the fabric. How do I remove this without destroying or decoloring the fabric?

Answer (score 3):

[Acetone and methyl ethyl ketone dissolve cyanoacrylate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyanoacrylate#Solvents_and_debonders), i.e. "superglue". These are used in nail polish remover, though the commercial polish removers might have water added, which slows dissolving. Acetone is also available in hardware stores, e.g. [Lowe's](https://www.lowes.com/pd/Jasco-32-fl-oz-Fast-to-Dissolve-Acetone/50298079).

**N.B.** These solvents are *highly* flammable and somewhat toxic. Use with caution! Also, test the solvent on a hidden piece of material to see if it affects the color of the garment.

Comment: Commenting to suggest that you warm the jeans on a radiator before trying, and stick to a dab cloth or cotton bud to apply it as ketones are pretty good at taking off the dye too.